# Postgresql, Variáveis para funções psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Estou tentando criar uma trigger function para remover um schema criado no banco de dados em função de um atributo idproj da tabela geo.projetos listada a seguir:

```
CREATE TABLE geo.projetos
(
    idproj serial NOT NULL,
    ... , -- outros atributos 
    CONSTRAINT projetos_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idproj),
    ... -- Outras constraints,
);
```

O schema é criado por um programa (python/psycopg2) concatenando `'proj_' || idproj`. Assim, gostaria de remover o schema correspondente ao deletar o registro na tabela `geo.projetos`.

Com esse objetivo criei a função a seguir:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geo.drop_schema_projeto_id()
RETURNS trigger as $dsp$
    DECLARE schema_to_drop text := 'proj_' || OLD.idproj::text;
    BEGIN
        DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS  schema_to_drop CASCADE;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Schema a ser removido: %', schema_to_drop;
        ETURN OLD;
    END;
$dsp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Criação do trigger:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
DROP TRIGGER  drop_schema_projeto_id ON geo.projetos;
CREATE TRIGGER drop_schema_projeto_id
    AFTER DELETE
    ON geo.projetos
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE geo.drop_schema_projeto_id();
```

No entanto, quando executo, por exemplo:

```
DELETE FROM geo.projetos WHERE idproj = 87;
```

Recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
NOTA:  esquema "schema_to_drop" não existe, ignorando
CONTEXTO:  comando SQL "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS  schema_to_drop CASCADE"
função PL/pgSQL geo.drop_schema_projeto_id() linha 5 em comando SQL
NOTA:  Schema a ser removido: proj_87
DELETE 1
```

Parece que o problema está na manipulação da variável `schema_to_drop` que não é substituída por `proj_87`.

Pergunto se haveria algum meio de conseguir que o comando `DROP SCHEMA` interprete a variável `schema_to_drop` com o valor que está carregado nela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `EXECUTE`, com ele você consegue gerar código SQL de forma dinâmica no plpgsql.

O comando `EXECUTE` roda o comando SQL informado na string. Utilizei a função `format` para permitir utilizar a variável `schema_to_drop` substituindo o `%I`. O `format` entende que onde há um `%I` haverá a substituição por um nome de um objeto do banco de dados.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geo.drop_schema_projeto_id()
RETURNS trigger as $dsp$
    DECLARE schema_to_drop text := 'proj_' || OLD.idproj::text;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS %I CASCADE;',schema_to_drop);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Schema a ser removido: %', schema_to_drop;
        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$dsp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Camilo Santos pela resposta.

Funcionou perfeitamente.
Grato também pelo link enviado.
Sendo assim considero a pergunta [SOLUCIONADA]

Comment: A maneira correta de informar que uma resposta foi útil não é acrescentar um comentário dizendo que foi solucionada e sim marcar a resposta como aceita Veja o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).